# Remove duplicate considering a couple of attributes in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, dataframe

I would like to exclude those instances that have the same title and the same year.

```
     title      votes  ranking  year
0    Wonderland  19      7.9    1931
1    Wonderland  120     7.1    1997
2    Wonderland  3524    7.2    1999
3    Wonderland  18169   6.6    2003
4    Wonderland  17      8.7    2010
5    Wonderland  6       8.5    2012
6    Wonderland  8       7.4    2012
```

For example, in this case. I would only remove 5 or 6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`drop_duplicates()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) with the `subset=` argument. If your dataframe is named `df`, you'd do:

```
In [13]: df.drop_duplicates(subset=['title', 'year'])
```

Which will return:

```
Out[13]:
        title  votes  ranking  year
0  Wonderland     19      7.9  1931
1  Wonderland    120      7.1  1997
2  Wonderland   3524      7.2  1999
3  Wonderland  18169      6.6  2003
4  Wonderland     17      8.7  2010
5  Wonderland      6      8.5  2012
```

Note that you lose any unique information from votes and ranking that were contained in index 6.